# How to Extract integer from character

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
            int num[10]   ;            
            sscanf(msg, "%d%d%d%d%", &num[0], &num[1], &num[2], &num[3]); 
            int x = num[0]; // integer
            int y = num[1]; // integer
            int z = num[2]; // integer
            int c = num[3]; // integer
```

I got problem from the above code, when I write '131249', so the result is:

```
x = 177 
y = -8755
z = -21206
c = -246
```

but the expected value should

```
x = 13 
y = 12
z = 4
c = 9
```

How to have the expected value, is there any wrong in my code ?

Comment: The string "131249" you input is interpreted as a single integer. (sscanf should return 1.) Try "13 12 4 9". The values of y, z and c are what happens to be in the memory there. (Although, admittedly, I cannot explain the value 177.)

Comment: If you write "131249" how can you expect 13 12 4 9? Why not 131 2 4 9 or 1 3 12 49?

Comment: PeterSchneider and Mateusz Kwaśniak , yes it worked with spacing, but the input is forced to "131249"

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense, you have to provide more context. What is the number representing, why do you expect to parse it in a certain way, where is the code doing that, what will you do with the result etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your values length is fixed, you may want to specify the lenght of each value you're trying to capture. Ex :

`sscanf(msg, "%2d%2d%1d%1d%", &num[0], &num[1], &num[2], &num[3]);`

Comment: what happen if the input comes from hexadecimal ? 
for example 0A ... 1F .. 12 ..

Comment: To read hexadecimal values, you should use %x instead of %d. The length attribute should also work (i.e: %2x)

Comment: if i have the value `0x33D` how to print separately ? like this , `0x03`  `0x3D`

Comment: No, you can keep your value as 0x33D, and use something like sscanf(msg, "0x%2x%1x", &num[0], &num[1]);

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to believe that if you did a printf of x that you'd see 177.  It should be 131249 based on your code.  Try Nicolas' suggestion.  You might also want to initialize your num array, i.e.

int num[10] = {0};

Comment: if `sizeof(int)==2`, 131249 will be stored as 177 (`131249 & 0xFFFF == 177`).